# notification with remote view shows blank

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-remoteview

When i am creating notification without remote view it's working fine,but when i try to use remote view,the notification shows a blank screen.
Here is my code for notification:-/

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
           R.layout.widget);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.date,result);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
         this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark).setContent(remoteViews);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationDatabase.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

and here is my widget.xml:-/

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/request"
    android:text="NEW APPOINTMENT REQUEST"
    android:textSize="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accept"
    android:id="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/request"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DENY"
    android:id="@+id/deny"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/accept"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CHECK SCHEDULE"
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deny"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OCT 12,12:10 PM, MON"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/request"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/request" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution for this? I am also having the same problem

Comment: Try manually changing the color to dark in widget.xml